# Jquery to extend functionality of dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently attempting to implement an image uploader. Unfortunately I am not a javascript programer, but luckily someone developed http://www.dropzonejs.com/. I attempting to enhance this javascript. One of the things I would like to implement is the ability to reorganize the images. To do so jquery will be used.

Below is a sample of all the html which makes up an image preview.

```
<div class="dz-preview dz-processing dz-image-preview dz-success">
<div class="dz-details">
<div class="dz-filename">
<div class="dz-size" data-dz-size="">
<img data-dz-thumbnail="" alt="2.png" src="">
</div>
<div class="dz-progress">
<div class="dz-success-mark">
<div class="dz-error-mark">
<div class="dz-error-message">
</div>
```

So I am attempting to create code which would allow me to reorganize the photos. To do so I am implementing some animate method, and then once that is done I will use jquery to cut and "paste" into new location.

method used for onclick when image preview is clicked(currently nothing is invoked.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.dz-details:image').bind( "click", function(){
console.log('clicked');
    var pos1 = $('#demo-upload').position();
    $(this).animate({ 'top': pos1.top + 'px', 'left': pos1.left + 'px'}, 200, function(){
        //probably find position here and insert div
    });
});
});
```

I will probably use the .remove() when a div is clicked and dragged. and use something similar to below to insert it into new location.

```
$(loca).append(div);'
```

Some direction would be helpful

Comment: If I copy and paste my code $('img').bind( "click", function(){
console.log('clicked');
}); into the console and then click on the item, it is invoked properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to alter the dropzone.js by adding a javascript onclick method call into the template

```
previewTemplate: "<div class=\"dz-preview dz-file-preview\" onclick=\"moveDiv(this)\" >\n     <div class=\"dz-details\">\n    <div class=\"dz-filename\"><span data-dz-name></span></div>\n    <div class=\"dz-size\" data-dz-size></div>\n    <img data-dz-thumbnail />\n  </div>\n  <div class=\"dz-progress\"><span class=\"dz-upload\" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div>\n  <div class=\"dz-success-mark\"><span>✔</span></div>\n  <div class=\"dz-error-mark\"><span>✘</span></div>\n  <div class=\"dz-error-message\"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>\n</div>"
    };
```